# Ubuntu 16.04: Sound and video problems

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 a while ago and I haven't gotten the sound to work ever since. Oddly enough, there's sound when I start up my computer, but none afterwards. There are no sound output devices detected:

[image: (click for image)]

In addition, at some point, the volume indicator disappeared from my task bar, and there's no check box in Sound Settings to put it back.

When I run `aplay -i`, nothing appears. At one point, I tried everything suggested in [this article on UnixMen.com](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/), including unmuting everything in `alsamixer`, reinstalling Alsa and `pulseaudio`, and updating my sound drivers (although I'm really, really worried that this might have made the problem worse), and I got the sound to work for a while, but when I restarted later, it stopped working again.

How can I fix this?

Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide - this problem has been plaguing me for the past few months.

Comment: As the answer posted below states `aplay -i` (lower case I) does nothing. Please update your question with the output from `aplay -l` (lower case L). Also add your computer make and model number to your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The command to display soundcards is `aplay -l` not `aplay -i`
- As there is sound at startup , try to disable speech-dispatcher running
  `sudo update-rc.d -f speech-dispatcher remove`
  and reboot
- If no luck, disable pulseaudio for testing, so you can check if underlaying alsa driver works fine. Run 3 commands::
  `mkdir ~/.pulse`
  `echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf`
  `pulseaudio -k`
  Now any audio softwares will use only alsa: test sound (check volumes and mute  using alsamixer or install  "alsamixergui ").
  If it is ok, pulseaudio is broken : reset it with
  `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulseold`
  `echo autospawn=yes > ~/.pulse/client.conf`
  `pulseaudio`
  This will launch pulseaudio with new configuration ,test again.